# BigCommerce API call after authentication

Tags: c#, .net, bigcommerce

I'm currently trying to write into the BigCommerce oauth API, but I am continually getting the following error:

**The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.**

I would like to return a listing of orders/customers/etc. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

A sample of my code is below.

```
        string baseURL = "https://api.bigcommerce.com/stores/" + storeHash + "/v2/" + resourcePath;
        string contentType = "application/json";

        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(baseURL);
        req.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
        req.ContentType = contentType;
        req.Method = "POST";

        req.Headers.Add("X-Auth-Client", clientID);
        req.Headers.Add("X-Auth-Token", token);

        string sendRequest = "min_id=1";

        byte[] postData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sendRequest);
        req.ContentLength = postData.Length;

        //Send the data to login server
        using (Stream stream = req.GetRequestStream()) {
            stream.Write(postData, 0, postData.Length);
            stream.Flush();
            stream.Close();
        }

        //Get the request response object

        WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();

        //Read the contents of the response
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
        string jsonResponse = sr.ReadToEnd();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to your comments, I was able to come up with this resolution:

```
        //BigCommerce Authorization//
        string clientID = "grmx4ghnscp8pz2jb4bf2qylt9b61yh";
        string clientSecret = "ibjh6whikzab0jm84zgjw5uydstx1b8";
        string token = "d56i5khv6l4kgcd9k92wpavyh93iqh";
        string storeHash = "pdcnmnye";
        string resourcePath = "products";

        string baseURL = "https://api.bigcommerce.com/stores/" + storeHash + "/v2/" + resourcePath;
        string requestParams = "?min_id=65&max_id=75";

        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(baseURL + requestParams);
        req.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
        req.ContentType = "application/json";
        req.Accept = "application/json";
        req.Method = "GET";

        //string authValue = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes("admin:" + ""));

        req.Headers.Add("X-Auth-Client", clientID);
        req.Headers.Add("X-Auth-Token", token);
        //req.Headers.Add("Authorization", authValue);

        Trace.Write("Base URL",baseURL);

        string jsonResponse = null;
        using (WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse()) {
            if (req.HaveResponse && resp != null) {
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream())) {
                    jsonResponse = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }

        Response.Write(jsonResponse);
```

Answer (score 1):

Is your request a properly formatted querystring? Such as .../v2/orders?min_id=1&max_id=10.

Comment: I took another look at your code; if you want to return a list of orders etc. then your method should be GET instead of POST in addition to my above comment.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try those out today. Appreciate your feedback!

Comment: Please let me know how you make out. Aside from myself you're the only other person I know of who has chosen to tackle the BC oauth2 API with .NET so it's nice to see.

Comment: So I got it working with the code above, however that was just for pulling data from the site. How do you go about passing JSON data to the site for creating products, orders, etc? Would that be something like this?

/stores/{store_hash}/v2/orders?json={"customer_id": 0,
  "status_id": 11,
  "date_created": "Thu, 04 Oct 2012 03:24:40 +0000",
  "subtotal_ex_tax": 1705,
  ...
}

Comment: it's pretty much the same, but instead you'll be using POST (or PUT in some cases) in conjunction with the proper resource path. Any JSON data would be the content of the POST request. The order ID you want to manipulate for instance, would remain as part of the resource path. The documentation for each resource has an example of the resource path, verb and required parameters along with sample responses.

Comment: Thanks! Really appreciate the feedback. You may see more posts/questions from me as I continue down this path. ;-)

Comment: I'm happy to help out. Let me know if you get stuck on something.